# FHIR Medication Order x1

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

How do I represent the x1 frequency in the Timing object of FHIR or in MedicationOrder?

http://hl7.org/fhir/2016Sep/datatypes.html#Timing

http://hl7.org/fhir/2016Sep/medicationorder.html

It doesn't have to happen at a specific time but it is not "as needed".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default assumption, in the absense of other timing information is "once".  You can also say

```
<repeat>
  <count value="1"/>
</repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was so simple, but I ignored "repeat" because it didn't repeat ha!  But this works for me.